Google Chrome PC: How to customize the new tab page?
I use Google Chrome (Version 131.0.6778.205 (Official Build) (64-bit)) on computer running Windows-11.
Some images out here suggest that the new tab page should  show a Customize button at the bottom right, but in my case there is no such button. How can I customize the new tab page? I would like to add frequently used sites and enable the search box.

Since you did not upload a screenshot, I am assuming it is one of the two:

You need to set Google Search as the default search to make the Customize Chrome button appear at the bottom right. Go to  chrome://settings/search and change it to Google Search.


This happens because every search engine you set it as default, has their own way to customize the new tab page. I have tried Bing, DuckDuck go, they all do it.


Assuming you have Google as your default search, and you still cannot see the option, you can go to chrome://settings/appearance and you should be able to customize, but nothing for the new tab, but everything else.


